# locate a selector on a paged screen with UIPath

Tags: uipath

I have a portal that holds a bunch of records for users. I am trying to automate changes to this by reading from a text file and adding, deleting, editing etc.

Example: the page loads it shows a result set of 50, but there are 115 records total, and I can click on an arrow to show the next group. In this case I'm saying I have a specific number of records and I already know how many pages that will require me to search through, but in the real world those numbers could be anything.

How can I search through all records to determine if the record I'm looking for exists? I assume there's an established way to do this, and I'm just not using the right terminology. FTR, I don't need to scrape the page, since I need to click on a control associated with a specific row in the table. The identifier is basically something like

```
If the RowName == {{var}} then click on the edit button on that row.
```

I assume I could math my way through this, but that seems kludge to me.

Comment: Not sure what you need. First you say you want to do something on the record. Then you say you want to only find a record. So the best solution depends on what you need. And this is a super basic question. Please go to the UiPath Academy for free tutorials. There you learn everything to solve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this on my side :

- Data scraping on the whole table/dataset and use the "Next page" functionality to handle the unknown number of pages

> How can I search through all records to determine if the record I'm looking for exists?

Now that you have a DataTable containing every record, it's easier for you to know what to do, assuming I understand you needs:

For each line of your text file, you can check if your record exist or not, create delete modify regarding this, and it will be **much faster** than checking on the Web Interface for every line!